# Equivalent code and classical approach of roll "shifting function" into loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a basic loop (actually time loop where values of an array are updated ) :

```
for i in range(1,nt):
    #Using roll
    u = u - cfl/2*(roll(u,-1)- roll(u,1))
    # Update time
    t = t+dt
```

With this loop and `roll` function, simulation is working fine.

I precise that I must have periodic boundaries conditions (`x[0] = x[n-1]`)

---

Now, I am trying to get the same equivalent code but with classical approach, I mean by write explicit code of what `roll` shifting function does.

From a previous post on another forum, one suggests to do :

```
for i in range(1,nt):
   utemp1 = u[0] - cfl/2*(u[nx-1] - u[1])
   utemp2 = u[nx-1] - cfl/2*(u[nx-2] - u[0])
   u[1:nx-2] = u[1:nx-2] - cfl/2*(u[0:nx-3] - u[2:nx-1])
   u[0] = utemp1
   u[nx-1] = utemp2
```

But this "equivalent code" doesn't produce the same results than with first version (with `roll` python function).

I would like to understand what is wrong into my assignments above. It seems to be an issue of overwritten values or bad updates on boundaries.

### Update 1

The following code seems to be correct for me:

```
for i in range(1,nt):
   utemp1=u[0] - cfl/2*(u[nx-1] - u[1])
   utemp2=u[nx-1] - cfl/2*(u[nx-2] - u[0])
   u[1:nx-2] = u[1:nx-2] - cfl/2*(u[0:nx-3] - u[2:nx-1])
   u[0] = utemp1
   u[nx-1] = utemp2
```

Except the fact that I am not sure if I should or not invert the two last assignments (since periodic boundary conditions):

```
   u[0] = utemp1
   u[nx-1] = utemp2
```

This "equivalent code" of "`roll`" Python function has to work "normally", this is only and unfortunately my impression since it doesn't produce the same result than the simple solution:

```
for i in range(1,nt):
    #Using roll
    u = u - cfl/2*(roll(u,-1)- roll(u,1))
```

Why does my explicit solution (explicit working of "`roll`" python function) not work ?

### Update 2

Following the request of `@Engineero`, I am supplying a small code that you can run simply with Python:

```
#
# Equation d'advection: u,t + V*u,x = 0
# centre FTCS (Forward Time Centered Space)
#

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *

# Speed
V = 1  
L = 1
# analytical solution --------------------------
def uexacte(t,x):
    return sin(2*pi*(x-V*t)/L)

# 1. Centre FTCS (Forward Time Centered Space)
cfl = 0.1
nx = 128
tend = 1

#
dx = L/(nx-1.)
dt = cfl*dx/V
nt = int(tend/dt)+1
print "CFL=%5.2f tend=%4.1f --> %i iterations en temps"%(cfl,tend,nt)

# Arrays
x = linspace(0,L,nx)
# Bounadry condition
u0 = uexacte(0,x)

# Starting solution
t=0.0 ; u=copy(u0)

# Time loop
for i in range(1,nt):
    # FTCS

    # Using classical approach
    utemp1=u[0] - cfl/2*(u[nx-1] - u[1])
    utemp2=u[nx-1] - cfl/2*(u[nx-2] - u[0])
    u[1:nx-1] = u[1:nx-1] - cfl/2*(u[0:nx-2] - u[2:nx])
    u[0] = utemp1
    u[nx-1] = utemp2
 
    #Using roll
    #u = u - cfl/2*(roll(u,-1)- roll(u,1))
    
    # Update time
    t = t+dt

    # Plot numerical solution and analytical
    #if (i % 2 == 0):
    plt.gcf().clear()
    # Numerical
    plt.ylim(ymin=-1.1, ymax=1.1)
    plt.title('FTCS Scheme - Unconditionally unstable - CFL=%5.2f'%cfl)
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('u')
    plt.plot(x,u,'-o',color='r',label='Numerical')
    # Analytical
    uexact= uexacte(t,x)
    plt.plot(x,uexact,'--',label='Analytical')
    plt.draw()
    plt.legend()
    plt.pause(0.1)

plt.pause(30)
```

If I use my classical approach (explicit working of "`roll`"), I don't get the analytical solution.

Here's an example of a capture during animation:

[image: results with explicit of roll function]

The analytical solution is given by `uexacte` function at the beginning of code :

```
sin(2*pi*(x-V*t)/L)
```

On the other side, by using "roll" function, I get the same results during animation between analytical and numerical solution (up to a some point).

### Update 3

I keep trying to make classical approach of `roll` by comparing the two formulas (with `nx=4`) in this way :

```
# Time loop
for i in range(1,nt):
    # FTCS

    # Using classical approach
    utemp1 = u[0] - cfl/2*(u[nx-1] - u[1])
    utemp2 = u[nx-1] - cfl/2*(u[nx-2] - u[0])
    u[1:nx-1] = u[1:nx-1] - cfl/2*(u[0:nx-2] - u[2:nx])
    u[0] = utemp1
    u[nx-1] = utemp2
    print "array u"
    print(u)

    #Using roll
    utest = utest - cfl/2*(roll(utest,-1) - roll(utest,1))
    print "array utest"
    print(utest)
```

At the execution, I get:

```
array u
[ 0.04330127  0.82272413 -0.90932667  0.04330127]
array utest
[-0.04330127  0.90932667 -0.82272413 -0.04330127]
array u
[ 0.08227241  0.77509274 -0.94829782  0.09093267]
array utest
[-0.09093267  0.94829782 -0.77509274 -0.08227241]
array u
[ 0.11648042  0.72356422 -0.98250582  0.14246118]
array utest
[-0.14246118  0.98250582 -0.72356422 -0.11648042]
```

As soon as I start with the first iteration, the 2 arrays values don't correspond and I don't understand why...

### Update 4

OK, I think that I have identified the issue:

If I do the assignment "multi-index" in once operation (I mean once time) :

```
u[1:nx-2] = u[1:nx-2] - cfl/2.0*(u[2:nx-1] - u[0:nx-3])
```

The assignment is badly performed and values of array `u` are not well computed.

If I test with the following simpler for "once-time sum and assignment" (with only 2 terms) :

```
u[1:nx-2] = u[1:nx-2] - u[2:nx-1]
```

The values `1:nx-2`of array `u` are correctly computed.

How to perform this natural and surely too simple form of the operation :

```
u[1:nx-2] = u[1:nx-2] - cfl/2.0*(u[2:nx-1] - u[0:nx-3])
```

??? (Maybe the factor doesn't apply to the difference `u[2:nx-1] - u[0:nx-3]`and also there is this difference added to u[1:nx-2], which may imply issues).

Comment: If it's the "same code", you should have unit tests to show that it works the same, no?

Comment: Could you give us an example (small) input and what you expect your output to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two equivalent functions:

```
nt=7
nx=10
cfl=1.1
def old(u0,cfl=-cfl):
    u=u0.copy()
    for i in range(1,nt):
        utemp1=u[0] - cfl/2*(u[nx-1] - u[1])
        utemp2=u[nx-1] - cfl/2*(u[nx-2] - u[0])
        u[1:nx-1] = u[1:nx-1] - cfl/2*(u[0:nx-2] - u[2:nx])
        u[0] = utemp1
        u[nx-1] = utemp2
    return u


def new(u0):
    u=u0.copy().astype(float)        
    for i in range(1,nt):
        u -=  cfl/2*(roll(u,-1)- roll(u,+1))
    return u
```

Mistakes in indices, sign of roll and type of `v` : it must be float.

runs :

```
In [521]: u0
Out[521]: array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])

In [522]: old(u0)
Out[522]: 
array([-15.06651094,  22.56142656,  28.93808047,  11.76161172,
         0.41970625,   1.41970625,  -9.92219922,   9.25426953,
        15.63092344, -19.99701406])

In [523]: new(u0)
Out[523]: 
array([-15.06651094,  22.56142656,  28.93808047,  11.76161172,
         0.41970625,   1.41970625,  -9.92219922,   9.25426953,
        15.63092344, -19.99701406])
```

Comment: -@B. M. thanks , why did you do `cfl=-cfl`into `old(u0,cfl=-cfl):` ?

Comment: -@B. M. could you test my code in **UPDATE 2** with python ?

Comment: -@B. M. I don't understand the line : `u[1:nx-1] = u[1:nx-1] - cfl/2*(u[0:nx-2] - u[2:nx])`, especially the term `u[2:nx]` since u has only `nx`elements, so index must not be greater than `nx-1`, hasn't it ?

Comment: Learn the language first. In python  a:b is from a included to b excluded.

Comment: -@B. M., thanks, I didn't know, I understand better now your solution.